# d3 Version acting as if it's a higher version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I've been working on a project that used d3 v5.5.0, moved it to another computer, and when I did npm install it now acts as if it's a higher version of d3?

Part of my program relies on the old way of d3 calling transform for zoom, and worked when it was that version. Yet even though in my packages it says it's got 5.5.0, it's throwing errors that event.transform was deprecated (Which happened in v6). How would it know it's deprecated if it should still be using 5.5.0? Also, if I do `npm list` it says the version of d3@^5.16.0? Which even then that doesn't make sense as you can see from my package.json.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "api": "npx json-server --watch .\\src\\components\\limit.json --port 8000"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "csvtojson": "^2.0.10",
    "d3": "^5.5.0",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-file-reader": "^1.1.4",
    "react-request": "^3.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.2",
    "react-scroll-wheel-handler": "^2.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "use-neo4j": "^0.3.5",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "write-json-file": "^4.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `package.json`, you have specified d3 to be `"^5.5.0"`. The `^` there says that the version to install must be **at least** version 5.5.0, so npm just installs the latest. If you want to force v5.5.0, you should specify it withput the `^`.
so your package.json should have `"d3": "5.5.0"` instead of `"d3": "^5.5.0"`

Comment: Using the carat will allow anything compatible with the version specified, which means any minor/patch version. If the deprecation truly didn't happen until 6.0.0 that wouldn't matter as the max version of d3 that could be installed would still be a 5.x.x.

Comment: You were exactly right. According to the d3 logs event wasn't deprecated until v6, however, it was still saying it was in v5.16.0. Thank you so much.